# Using simpleHTMLDOM to only grab a specific div class grabs the entire page instead

Tags: php, html

Hello Stackoverflow I'm trying to use the following library [simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

The purpose of this little script is to grab the StackOverflow Logo and echo it. But for some strange reason it grabs every DOM element instead. Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$request_url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
$html = file_get_html($request_url);

$element = $html->find('div[id=hlogo]');

echo $html->save($element);
```

Thank you in advance for taking your time to read this!

Comment: Did you try `echo` only `$element` or if its an array or object then `print_r`

Comment: @LaciK tried print_r too. It still sends back the full page DOM

Comment: I tried it out on a simple html file and I think this php class is broken, because it not simply outputs the dom it outputs it I don't know how many times duplicated. try to use php DOMDocument or SimpleXML or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

`$html->find` returns an array in the form that you're using it, so you need to access the first element of the array to get the results:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://stackoverflow.com');
$logo = $html->find('#hlogo'); // find the id hlogo

echo $logo[0];

# prints out
# <div id="hlogo"> <a href="/"> Stack Overflow </a> </div>
```

You're also using the `save` function wrong; from the docs:

```
// Dumps the internal DOM tree back into string 
$str = $html->save();

// Dumps the internal DOM tree back into a file 
$html->save('result.htm');
```

You're getting the whole page because `$html` contains the whole DOM!